# How to use a model when the input size changes?

Tags: python, pytorch

It is an encoder for images:

```
def __init__(self, secret_size):
    super(StegaStampEncoder, self).__init__()
    self.secret_dense = Dense(secret_size*8, 7500, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')
    self.secret_dense = self.secret_dense.cuda()
    self.conv1 = Conv2D(6, 32, 3, activation='relu')    # concat增加的是channel
    self.conv2 = Conv2D(32, 32, 3, activation='relu', strides=2)
    self.conv3 = Conv2D(32, 64, 3, activation='relu', strides=2)
    self.conv4 = Conv2D(64, 128, 3, activation='relu', strides=2)
    self.conv5 = Conv2D(128, 256, 3, activation='relu', strides=2)
    self.up6 = Conv2D(256, 128, 3, activation='relu')
    self.conv6 = Conv2D(256, 128, 3, activation='relu')
    self.up7 = Conv2D(128, 64, 3, activation='relu')
    self.conv7 = Conv2D(128, 64, 3, activation='relu')
    self.up8 = Conv2D(64, 32, 3, activation='relu')
    self.conv8 = Conv2D(64, 32, 3, activation='relu')
    self.up9 = Conv2D(32, 32, 3, activation='relu')
    self.conv9 = Conv2D(70, 32, 3, activation='relu')
    self.residual = Conv2D(32, 3, 1, activation=None)
```

It accepts input with (400, 400, 3) in size.
But now I want to apply it for images with (32, 32, 3) in size.
How can I train the model for such new images?

I'll appreciate if someone out there can help out.

I don't know whether I have to change the structure of this model.

Comment: you have 2 options
1- modify the  model to take 32x32x3 images .
2- resize images to 400x400x3 then pass it to model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But how can I modify the model to take 32*32*3 images?

Comment: you can use this website to know how much strid and padding you need to make to reach from 400x400 input to 32x32x3 output https://madebyollin.github.io/convnet-calculator/ , you will have to change the layers of the model `Conv2D(32, 3, 1, activation=None)` 32 is the input channels and 3 is the output channels not the width and height of image use the website to know the how many layers you need to make and each layer should use how many strid or padding. it depend on you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the StegaStampEncoder from this [github page](https://github.com/tancik/StegaStamp)

The `StegaStampEncoder` is defined in models.py and its init method takes height and width arguments:

`def __init__(self, height, width):`

When defining your model, pass those arguments with the desired values and you should be good to go, though reducing the input size that drastically might cause the model to malfunction.